# linked-list is always getting NULL even after adding elements to it

Tags: c, linked-list

I tied to list the linked-list, but nothing happen. It looks like my list is `NULL` even if I add elements to it. The function `insertTete` adds element to the begin of the list. `affichListe` lists the content of the list.
What I did is created a list called `maillon` then gave it an alias `liste` using `typdef maillon liste`. Then I created a variable named `liste* l` in `int main` and passed that variable to function as parameter. When I use `printf` inside `insertTete` it shows me the values, so `insertTete` working but when I try to call `affichListe` function it does not show anything.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct eleve {
    char nom[20];
    char prenom[20];
    int val;
};

struct maillon {
    eleve ele;
    maillon *suivant;
};

typedef maillon liste;

void insertTete(liste *premier, eleve ele) {
     liste *nouvEleve;
     nouvEleve = (liste *)malloc(sizeof(liste));
     nouvEleve->ele = ele;
     nouvEleve->suivant = premier;
     premier = nouvEleve; 
}

liste *dernier(liste *premier) {
    while (premier != NULL)
        premier = premier->suivant;
    return premier;
}

void affichListe(liste *premier) {
    while (premier != NULL) {
        printf("Nom etudiant: %s", premier->ele.nom);
        printf("Prenom etudiant: %s", premier->ele.prenom);
        printf("Note etudiant: %i", premier->ele.val);
    }
}

int main() {
    eleve ele;
    liste *l = NULL;
    
    strcpy(ele.nom, "Ahmed");
    strcpy(ele.prenom, "bejaoui");
    ele.val = 15;
    insertTete(l, ele);
    printf("%i", l == NULL);
    affichListe(l);
}
```

Comment: Run debugger and debug it. It is so simple program full of bugs which is easy to find when debugging. BTW it will not compile as well.

Comment: `premier = nouvEleve;` in  `insertTete(()` does not affect  `l` in `main()`.

Comment: `while(premier!=NULL)` in  `affichListe()` is an infinite loop, once the loop is entered.

Comment: yeah i got it now after changing the code to @Equod code , it worked, as u said its an infinite loop i will look for a solution for it,

Comment: i think i got the problem, i forget to put ```'premier = premier->suivant``` inside while loop

Comment: English is the language of programming, meaning variables, function names and other should be in English. It is fine to have inputs and outputs in other languages, but the programming should be in English. Then, I had a really hard time getting some sense out of your question. Try to explain your problem as clearly and to the point as possible. And it is clear that English is not your best attribute, I honestly think you could have written your question in french and translate it with google translate to get a better result...

Answer (score 2):

The issue is l's value is never modified. You should pass it as a pointer to a pointer

```
void insertTete(liste** premier, eleve ele) {
  liste* nouvEleve;
  nouvEleve = (liste*) malloc(sizeof(liste));
  nouvEleve->ele = ele;
  nouvEleve->suivant = *premier;
  *premier = nouvEleve;
}
```

or assign it from the return value

```
liste* insertTete(liste* premier, eleve ele) {
  liste* nouvEleve;
  nouvEleve = (liste*) malloc(sizeof(liste));
  nouvEleve->ele = ele;
  nouvEleve->suivant = premier;
  premier = nouvEleve;
  return premier;
}

l = insertTete(l, ele);
```

Comment: thanks for you answer, now its fixed but shows infinite loop in affichList()

Comment: You should modify premier in while loop: premier = premier->suivant;

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- `insertTete()` should take a pointer to the head pointer so the caller's variable is updated.
- `dernier()` should loop `while (premier->suivant)`. As currently coded, it always returns `NULL`.
- in `affichListe()` you should update `premier` to point to the next node inside the loop body.

Here is a modified version:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct eleve {
    char nom[20];
    char prenom[20];
    int val;
};

struct maillon {
    eleve ele;
    maillon *suivant;
};

typedef maillon liste;

liste *insertTete(liste **premier, eleve ele) {
    liste *nouvEleve = malloc(sizeof(liste));
    if (nouvEleve) {
        nouvEleve->ele = ele;
        nouvEleve->suivant = *premier;
        *premier = nouvEleve; 
    }
    return nouvEleve;
}

liste *dernier(liste *premier) {
    if (premier != NULL) {
        while (premier->suivant != NULL)
            premier = premier->suivant;
    }
    return premier;
}

void affichListe(const liste *premier) {
    while (premier != NULL) {
        printf("Nom étudiant: %s\n", premier->ele.nom);
        printf("Prénom étudiant: %s\n", premier->ele.prenom);
        printf("Note étudiant: %i\n\n", premier->ele.val);
    }
}

int main() {
    eleve ele;
    liste *l = NULL;
    
    strcpy(ele.nom, "Ahmed");
    strcpy(ele.prenom, "Bejaoui");
    ele.val = 15;
    insertTete(&l, ele);
    affichListe(l);
    return 0;
}
```